# Cannot save TimeSpan in user settings wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, timespan, settings

I have time to respawn which is saved as timespan in file mysettings.settings. I am trying to save new timespan in user.config by changing text in textbox. The code:

```
    public NewWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tbInt.Text = Properties.MySettings.Default.SomeInt.ToString();
        tbRespawnTime.Text = Properties.MySettings.Default.TimeToRespawn.TotalSeconds.ToString();
    }


    private void tbRespawnTime_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         Properties.MySettings.Default.TimeToRespawn = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(tbRespawnTime.Text));

    }

    private void btSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.MySettings.Default.Save();
    }
```

The problem is that new timespan is saving in user.config, but when i'm trying to show it in textbox in new instance of my application it's again default value from mysettings.settings

What am I doing wrong?

prefix "tb" means textbox
"bt" means button

Comment: what are the type and scope settings in your Property settings

Comment: the type is System.TimeSpan and scope is User

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Does the `SomeInt` setting work correctly? If so, maybe you should just store the respawn time in seconds as an integer, instead of as a TimeSpan.

Comment: I just ran into this on `Visual Studio 2017`. Every setting saves except for `typeof TimeSpan`. Haven't been able to pin point the cause, I suspect it may have something to do with saving / serializing `lists of objects` in the user settings.  For now, I had to change the value to a `long` and use `TimeSpan.FromTicks()` while getting and setting the value. But why?

Answer (score 1):

Bind directly in xaml like this,

```
Text="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=TimeToRespawn}"

xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:yourapplication.Properties"
```